# angular 6 Router.navigate right click not giving the option to "open in a new tab"

Tags: angular6, angular-router

As the title says when doing a right click on a button that has a click event of router.navigate(['somewhere']), I don't get the options to open in a new tab of window.

picture from [this url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Idguj.png) is what I get. picture from [that url](https://cloud.addictivetips.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/mapme1.jpg) is what I want.

I know it can be done with  tags but I would like to know how to do it with angular.

Thanks team!